# Django modelform ForeignKey List

Tags: django, django-forms

How do you get each item in the ForeignKey field in a list, for example:

```
class Delegate(models.Model):
    excursion = models.ForeignKey(Excursion, limit_choices_to = {'is_activity': False}, related_name='excursion', null=True, blank=True)
```

Template:

```
{% for object in formset.excursion_set.all %}
 {{ object.lable }}
 etc
{% endfor %}
```

My reason is that I don't want the options to display as a dropdown, but in a custom way that I will style etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't post the form from which the formset is being built... but assuming all instances of `Excursion` are acceptable values, you can simply store the possible field values in a context variable:

```
# in your view...
context = {}
excursions = Excursion.objects.all()
return render_to_response('your_template.html', context, context_instance = RequestContext(request))

# in your template...
{% for e in excursions %}
{{ e }}
{% endfor %}
```